# I took my back wheel off and chain will NOT go back on

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, chain

I took my back wheel off of my back to change the tube, when I put it back on i realized the chain wasn’t going back on the pedal, it’s very hard to explain it but it looks like a part of the chain is on the wrong side of the bike if that makes any sense, I’ve sunk hours tryna fix it but nothing works, please help me

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Bicycles.SE    Please include some pictures of your bike; right now we have no idea what's _right_ let alone what might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture showing how a chain should be routed:

[image]

<sub>Original source: https://www.popularmechanics.com/adventure/outdoor-gear/a22061530/how-bike-gears-work/</sub>

When fitting the wheel, you have to put the cogs side "into" the chain before lifting it up past the rear derailleur into the final dropout.

Comment: This is presuming you haven't split the chain, so it is still dangling on the bike.

Comment: Image is slightly confusing as the chain should be behind the seat stay and the drive side crank.

Comment: @Megavole good point - this is showing how the chain is routed.  Fixed.   (also I just noticed spokes are visible through the stays too, so its more of a "xray" )

Answer (score 0):

Look how the chain is routed on other bicycles around you. The path is seldom specific.